# How to fix my trigger which isn't deleting

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am working on a e-commerce site for a school project and i need to add a trigger in my project.

I choose to add a trigger which, when the product stock is equal to zero, the product is deleted and added in a historic table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER stock_produit_0 BEFORE UPDATE
ON produit FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.StockProduit = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO historique_produit(
          idProduit,
          PrixProduit,
          PoidProduit,
          NomProduit,
          DescriptionProduit,
          CouleurProduit,
          idclient,
          dateDelete)
          VALUES(
          OLD.idProduit,
          OLD.PrixProduit,
          OLD.PoidProduit,
          OLD.NomProduit,
          OLD.DescriptionProduit,
          OLD.CouleurProduit,
          OLD.idclient,
          NOW());
DELETE FROM produit WHERE idProduit = OLD.idProduit;
END IF;
END
```

Now, the trigger is working on the server but, when i buy a product, the product stock go to 0 but is not deleted

Comment: I am using MySQL with PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I decided to cut my trigger in two other trigger.
The first one is the trigger which insert into the table historique_produit when the stock equal to zero and it's working.
But now, i have do code something which DELETE my product from produit when the stock equal to zero.
I do not know if this is possible.
If it's not, i think i will keep my product in the table and i won't show it on the page which show the product

```
BEGIN 
IF NEW.StockProduit = 0 THEN
BEGIN
INSERT INTO historique_produit(
          idProduit,
          PrixProduit,
          PoidProduit,
          NomProduit,
          DescriptionProduit,
          CouleurProduit,
          idclient,
          dateDelete)
          VALUES(
          OLD.idProduit,
          OLD.PrixProduit,
          OLD.PoidProduit,
          OLD.NomProduit,
          OLD.DescriptionProduit,
          OLD.CouleurProduit,
          OLD.idclient,
          NOW());
END;
END IF;
END
```